# No desktopSDK found in TideSDK Developer

Tags: tidesdk

when searching the internet, i came across the TideSDK which I learnt was made for develoing desktop apps with HTML, CSS & Javascript.  As an experienced web designer I downloaded it hoping to begin creating desktop apps with my HTML, CSS & Jscript experience immediately.  But, that wasn't the case.

Immediately I launched it I saw just two buttons one to import, the other to create new project.  Since I had nothing to import, i opt to create new project.  After filling the spaces for project type(project type was fixed on desktop), name, app id, directory, company/personal URL,the Titanium SDK Version was left inactive ( I don't know why but i thought it was minor), I expected to see some spaces to write my codes but none.  Rather after saving my changes, I brought to a 'console' which was also inactive. No cursor at all except some buttons with lauch app, kill app, package with Runtime, package without runtime which were all not yielding any result. Infact after clicking each of them, I still remained in the inactive console.

In my curiousity to get things working, I have done many researches on the net without a fruitful result. The best article I have gotten so far is from: http://seyekuyinu.com/how-to-set-up-the-tide-sdk-developing-desktop-applications-with-html5-css3-and-javascript/ but even that did not work fine. I downloaded the Tiv Community App which suppose to serve as the IDE but it could not be installed.The installer always stop on the way. I have tried to instal it on my home laptop and the office desktop but it could not be completed in any of them. Please if you want to reply to this question, i would love you to download the Tiv Community app and see what am talking about. I have also downloaded the helloworld from Github but when I try to import, it gives an error message something like "Importing desktop project, but not desktop SDK found in your system". I downloaded the desktopsdk-1.2.0.C4-win32 but the installer is not work - 'cannot locate application path'.

Please, am curious about this whole project and would appreciate any useful reply. I would also appreciate if TideSDK Developer team could write a comprehensive 'getting started guide' but the guide avaiable now is not meeting up with our curiousity for getting started in SDK. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Getting Started Guide http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

TideSDK's latest release version is 1.3.1-beta

You need to download the SDK from http://tidesdk.org and extract the same in appropriate directory as mentioned in getting started guide.